# Как экспортировать html в doc

Tags: javascript, html, css, docx, doc

Как осуществить экспорт средствами js с сохранением стилей css... inline css не подходит...
может посоветует кто чего...

Comment: А также желательно избежать изменений в самой верстке(страницы выполнены на vue... вызовы методов,циклы и условия находятся в template)

Comment: https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js этот не подойдет?